# how to calculate accurate height of a label if it contains text with more spaces in iOS?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, height, uilabel

I just finding how to calculate exact height of label. I read same questions but my problem is different regarding the height of label. Following code I am using for calculating dynamic height of cell depending upon the label height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        CGSize size;
        Comment *objCommnt = [arrOfComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *msg = objCommnt.comment;

        CGSize textSize = { 260.0, 10000.0 };
        size = [msg sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
               constrainedToSize:textSize
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        size.height += padding;
        return size.height+padding +5;

        return 100;
}
```

where padding is

```
      static CGFloat padding = 20.0;
```

For commennts having proper spacing it gives me correct size and it works find as show in below image:[image]

For comments having text with continuous word means having huge space between two word gives me woring height as show in image below
[image]

I second image you can see what is my issue. What I am done for checking how much height required for that same lable checked in nib file by putting labels it's **92** when i am calulating its height dynamic its calculted as **80** why is it so ?? **I think its due to more spacing between two words or longer word then space after it**  Any body has any idea why is it like that any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your label width to 260px but is that the actual width of the label in the table view?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height is easy, enjoy:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    Comment *objCommnt = [arrOfComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellText = objCommnt.comment;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0f];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(260.0, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont 
                            constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20.0f;
}
```

Hope it will help!

UPDATE!!!
You only need:

```
return size.height+padding +5;
```

Instead of:

```
return size.height+padding +5;

        return 100;
```